# Scaling & positioning <video> for different resolutions

Tags: html, css, json, media-queries, resolution

So, I want to scale & position my video on a website depending on the users resolution.
I came across media query but didn't get it to work. My idea that I don't know how to execute is:
If a resolution is between 1800x1000-1920x1080 then the video will be position absolute; ____ & width, height etc: ______. And then IF 1200x800-1400x1000 then the video will be position absolute; ____ & width, height etc: ______. and so on.

Would this work? Is there a better way to do it? Thanks

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
         video {
            position: absolute;
            margin-top: -96%;
            margin-left: 980px;
            margin-right: 980px;
            width: 360px;
            display: none;
        }
     
      
    </style>

</head>

<body>
       
    <video id="PrintMusic" autoplay>        
        <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/1ef399dd4bb345e485f6e4784a9d0031.mp4">  
     
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</body>

<body>

    <button onclick="playVideo()">Play</button>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function playVideo() {

            const video = document.querySelector('video');

            video.style.setProperty('display', 'block');

            video.play();

            const button = document.querySelector('button');

            button.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this code below.

Don't forget to use the `!important` to force the CSS from the original one.

```
@media (min-width: 1800px) and (max-width: 1920px)  {
    video {
       position : absolute; 
       width: XXX !important;
       height: XXX !important;
   }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1400px)  {
    video {
       position : absolute; 
       width: XXX !important;
       height: XXX !important;
    }
}
```

If you want a better way to do it, use something like :

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    // responsive video 
}
```

Example of a snippet here :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Static Template</title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
  /* body{
  background-color:lightgray;
} */
  
  video {
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    height: 600px;
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1800px) and (max-width: 1920px) {
    video {
      position: absolute;
      width: auto !important;
      height: 200px !important;
    }
  }
  
  @media (min-width: 1200px) and (max-width: 1400px) {
    video {
      position: absolute;
      width: auto !important;
      height: 400px !important;
    }
  }
</style>

</head>

<body>

  <video id="PrintMusic" autoplay>        
        <source src="https://cdn.shopify.com/videos/c/o/v/1ef399dd4bb345e485f6e4784a9d0031.mp4" type="video/mp4">  
     
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>

</body>
```

Comment: Hey, couldn't get this to work. Either I'm doing it wrong or some other problem occurs

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the `video` class in the `@media`, try again now

Comment: I added you a snippet example, which works well if you decrease / increase the screen size :)